# Manually Parse Form Data Node.js Express

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data, filereader

How can I parse form-data manually at node js?
I get **chunks** of the large file at the server side. And can't merge it, because it will borrow RAM equals to the (file size + file info size).

As far as I understand, I can't use the libraries, such as multer/connect-busboy/connect-multiparty etc.

In simple terms, now I get following data at server side and can't figure out how to receive, example, a file name, and how to determine, which byte is responsible for the beginning of the file.

```
[1] Get request...
[1] data:  <Buffer 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 57 65 62 4b 69 74 46 6f 72 6d 42 6f 75 6e 64 61 72 79 62 66 30 31 63 62 36 38 71 4d 41 4d 36 6d 51 31 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d ... 65486 more bytes>
[1] data:  <Buffer 02 10 00 00 01 ce 00 00 01 ef 00 00 14 e4 00 00 01 de 00 00 01 b2 00 00 01 d8 00 05 f0 1a 00 00 06 70 00 00 00 fa 00 00 00 cf 00 00 0a 3b 00 00 01 4a ... 65486 more bytes>
[1] data:  <Buffer 31 52 2e 9a 5b df 11 19 5f c2 5d 38 ed db 23 00 06 05 bd 8f 71 e7 6b 03 9d 3a 88 e3 24 10 00 0f a1 10 43 82 ff 67 bd 5d eb 8e 59 fe a9 d3 e6 45 f2 9e ... 65486 more bytes>
[1] data:  <Buffer 2b 6c cf 18 40 13 d8 fd 09 fa 56 25 e6 6d 6a 57 94 8c a4 9c d1 7b 99 bb 20 c0 21 e7 4a 1f 72 5a a5 3d 8e 84 5d 97 eb 1b 0f db b1 a9 81 f9 db ef 06 36 ... 65486 more bytes>
[1] data:  <Buffer bb 29 4b 0d 06 1d 69 e1 c7 47 a7 99 c6 e4 c3 48 2e 85 6a b3 57 01 68 09 00 aa 6d b4 7b c7 07 2f 73 c0 c4 6b c4 48 9b 8f 81 64 8e 25 c7 a3 de c3 4f 2a ... 65486 more bytes>
[1] data:  <Buffer 21 2b 1c dd 57 02 23 f5 43 a1 70 72 b4 8d 8d a8 4a 4b c1 e1 21 75 84 ed 07 00 34 de 5c 8d b0 0a 6f 99 60 28 34 b1 c5 bd a2 3c 3e d5 01 0f 62 57 a8 e8 ... 65486 more bytes>
[1] data:  <Buffer 2d 96 e3 47 75 ce 25 63 77 26 15 96 b6 43 b9 d2 59 7d 12 c9 64 b2 11 f2 39 29 3e bf 83 1a f3 15 7b 14 ee f3 33 52 5c 39 34 75 06 41 2f e7 11 e8 26 4e ... 65486 more bytes>
[1] data:  <Buffer 4a 9d 20 c7 a8 55 35 22 26 ff c7 b4 11 d9 6c 4d ce e1 a0 b2 b3 01 37 da 6a ad ae 98 fd 9b 8e 9c 8b 4a 27 8e e3 10 4a dc 80 f2 50 df 88 d9 c8 f9 ef 48 ... 65486 more bytes>
[1] data:  <Buffer 52 ee b3 96 1f 7c af df fa 3f 9c 9a f7 01 20 7d 3f ea 4e 7e aa 4e d9 57 31 cb b5 f3 09 49 c7 ee 92 83 2e cb 58 d2 ea 1b b0 35 2a 3c 6c 27 75 0c d0 39 ... 65486 more bytes>
...more
...more
...and more
```

After receiving all the above data, I need to get file name and send **each chunk of the file**(not other info, such as name/mime type) to **another client**. (It's file sharing web resource)

Another solutions?

1. At the same time, I could to send the file separated **manually** by the chunks of type ArrayBuffer. Each chunk would be encoded additional information, like a "file name", "mime type". But in this case, I should to separate file at client side and get again the above problem the lack of memory.
2. A working solution, but a bit insecure. Send the file name and mime type separately from the main file data.

The part of the code responsible for sending data:

```
  app.get(`/${senderId}/get`, (request, response) => {
    let countChunks = 0;
    // waiting for the sender's request now...

    app.post(`/${senderId}/send`, (requestSender, responseSender) => {
      // start sharing...
      let countChunks = 0;

      requestSender.on("data", (chunk) => {
        if (countChunks === 0) {
          // need get the name from the chunks
          const fileName = "test_name";
          response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", `attachment; filename="${fileName}"`);
        }
        countChunks += 1;

        // need to get the first byte of the file data and start sending starting with it
        response.write(chunk);
      })
      requestSender.on("end", () => {
        response.end();
      })
    })
  })
```

Comment: P.S: Save the getting file to the server is unacceptable. The main feature is to send file without saving file at the server side. Chunk by chunk from first user to the second user.

Comment: If your server doesn't have enough memory for processing user uploads, stop allowing insanely huge user uploads. Your server has _plenty_ of memory for assembling normal sized files before writing it to disk under normal circumstances.

Comment: Ok, I got it, but "The main feature is to send file from user to user without saving this one at the server side. Chunk by chunk from first user to the second user."

Comment: Just have the client talk http, and have it accept POST instructions so you can proxy the upload? Without more details in the post (and code. If your problem is with code, showing code [helps _a lot_](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Added some code